# При вставке float в SQLite не верно записуются значения

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate, float

Через Hibernate вставляю значения в таблицу. Передаю числа с запятой: 3,5 или 1,44 и тд и некоторые(не все) в таблицу уже записуются как 3.50000004768372 и 1.44000005722046

Как можно исправить положение? Почему в БД такие преобразования?

Comment: Вы уверены, что 3.5 записывается как 3.70000004768372, а не 3.50000004768372?

Comment: Попробуйте `double` вместо `float`

Comment: напишите код, которым вы вставляете значения

Comment: @AntonShchyrov моя ошибка. Да, так как вы пишите